# Simplifying a rational function on an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, rational-functions, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Does a rational function $\phi$ on a smooth projective algebraic curve $F$
over a algebraically closed field $K$ always have a representative
$\frac{f}{g}$, where $f$ and $g$ are polynomials without common zero on $F$ ?

I think that it is a consequence of Max Noether's fundamental theorem
($AF + BG$ theorem), which would in this sense be the analogon of the
fundamental theorem of algebra (simplification of rational functions over
$\mathbb{C}$).